# StyleCop for MVC application

Tags: coding-style, stylecop

We are planning to use [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) for our MVC application. 
Has anyone used StyleCop for MVC? 
It would be great if I could get the pros and cons for using style cop.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using StyleCop for a while with the application software that I've been writing, and it's been a great tool for enforcing a standard coding style.  The most important thing to take into it is an attitude that one style, generally, is as good as another-- there isn't one that's objectively superior.  With that simple understanding, StyleCop will end up being a powerful tool that makes code reading, navigation, and maintenance simpler across the board.

I haven't really encountered any genuine cons for stylecop.  I suspect that some people might claim the fact that its styles aren't configurable beyond whether a particular rule is or isn't enforced to be a con, but I don't think that it is.  The tool exists to enforce a uniform style across the board, and if you could configure it to require `this.` prefixes or not, then that would defeat the purpose.